# Word or phrase completion based on file

Tags: autocompletion

I would like to create a file people.txt which has contents such as

```
George Bush
Hillary Clinton
Santa Clause
```

If I am in vi and type "Clau", vi suggests "Santa Clause".
Likewise, if I type "eorg", vi suggests "George Bush".

I want to be able to manually update the people.txt file
and have the new completions to work automatically.

Has this been done? If so, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You'll want to read `:help 'completefunc'` and `:help complete-functions`